# Custom UIControl within UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicontrol

I have a custom `UIControl` which can have two custom states -> `customEnabled` / `customDisabled`. State change of this `UIControl` results technically in hiding / displaying defined view for the  state set. Work fine so far.

When using within the `UITableView` I have the following problem: When reusing a cell with enabled control for a cell, where control is disabled I see for a short time the enabled and then disabled control.

State setting is happening in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of the `UITableViewController`. The setter for the state shows / hides the views.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the appropriate appearance without "animation"?

Comment: A little bit of code will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your showing/hiding in the following

```
[CATransaction begin]; 
[CATransaction setValue: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];
// do show/hide
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thx! That works. Does it mean, hidden property changes are default animated?

Comment: Yes, they are. Mark the post as an answer if it solves the problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest something similar

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
    // Code with animations turned off
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}];
```